# Fetching only last row from PHP MySql in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, pagination

Developing quiz application using Android - PHP MySql(DataBase)
It's fetching only last row from the database, I want to implement and to fetch data one by one on next click.

So it will work like quiz

here is the recent code

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try
        {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(res); 

            quizID =(json_data.getString("quizID")); 
            question =(json_data.getString("question")); 
            choice1 =(json_data.getString("choice1")); 
            choice2 =(json_data.getString("choice2")); 
            choice3 =(json_data.getString("choice3")); 
            answer =(json_data.getString("answer")); 

            txtno.setText("No. " + quizID); 
            txtque.setText("" + question); 
            ropt0.setText("" + choice1); 
            ropt1.setText("" + choice2); 
            ropt2.setText("" + choice3); 
            ranswer.setText("" + answer);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }   
    }
```

PHP select.php code

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$uname='root';
$pwd='';
$db="QuizDB";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pwd,$db) or die("connection failed");

$quizID=$_REQUEST['quizID'];
$question=$_REQUEST['question'];
$choice1=$_REQUEST['choice1'];
$choice2=$_REQUEST['choice2'];
$choice3=$_REQUEST['choice3'];
$answer=$_REQUEST['answer'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM QuizQuestion"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $flag['quizID']=$row["quizID"];
    $flag['question']=$row["question"];
    $flag['choice1']=$row["choice1"];
    $flag['choice2']=$row["choice2"];
    $flag['choice3']=$row["choice3"];
    $flag['answer']=$row["answer"];
}

print(json_encode($flag));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Please suggest some solution and how to implement next & previous functionality

Comment: Where is the PHP code?

Comment: @AakashVerma I updated it, please check

Comment: Before the loop, define flag as an array. Then replace each instance of $flag inside the loop with $flag[]. Then, after your loop, json_encode your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is because once you're having the flag object with, say first record in the table, you are not using it and just overwriting it with data in next record on the next execution of the while-loop.

Do something like:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $flag['quizID']=$row["quizID"];
    $flag['question']=$row["question"];
    $flag['choice1']=$row["choice1"];
    $flag['choice2']=$row["choice2"];
    $flag['choice3']=$row["choice3"];
    $flag['answer']=$row["answer"];
    ...send flag object to wherever you  want...
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

To implement click for one-by-one results, keep a single counter for clicks for **Next** and **Previous** buttons and when one of them is pressed, send the  value to a similar script where you can modify the query like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY quizID LIMIT "+counter+"-1,1"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $flag['quizID']=$row["quizID"];
    $flag['question']=$row["question"];
    $flag['choice1']=$row["choice1"];
    $flag['choice2']=$row["choice2"];
    $flag['choice3']=$row["choice3"];
    $flag['answer']=$row["answer"];
}
```

Similarly do a script for previous. Manage the counter well. Initially initialize it to 1. That is when **Next** is pressed increase the counter by 1 and decrease it by 1 when **Previous** is pressed.